# Programmatically detecting mouse hover over taskbar/window caption (winforms/C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to find out if the mouse is hovering over a taskbar button, and the caption / hwnd of the window that belongs to the button. E.g. if you move the mouse over a taskbar button, you get the tooltip with the name - so this should be possible fairly easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve that task you should monitor explorer.exe incoming messages using Win32 API hooks. If you don't know about Win32 API then I suggest you to read a book about it and spent some time practicing, because Win32 API and its hooks can not be explained in short words of that answer.

C# is not a right tool to do sush sort of things, at least hooking must be done in C(++), so you need to learn it. Realistically speaking, that learning of Win32 API together with C(++) may took a year or two before the task become solvable.