# Show ToolTip When Application is in Minimized State

Tags: c#, tooltip

Can any help with this, i have an app, i want to show tooltip when application is minized & mouse hover over it.

Thanks

Comment: You mean in the taskbar?

Comment: This is kind of unclear.  Where exactly do you want to show the tooltip?  Will the app be minimized to the system tray or will it just reside in the task bar?

Comment: more details please: are you using winforms, do you mean the NotifyIcon etc...

Comment: sorry about that, it'll be minimized to taskbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445380/programmatically-detecting-mouse-hover-over-taskbar-window-caption-winforms-c

Comment: I'm using Window Form, also i'm making this App for Windows 7 so on mousehover it shows Thumbnail of Application how do i disable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is change the caption of your main form when the window goes to a minimized state. That way, when the user hovers over the minimized window, he sees the caption. This is the only way you can accomplish something like this.